# Возврат значения перечисления

Tags: javascript, enum, prisma

Допустим у меня в схеме есть такое перечисление:

```
enum Role {
  USER  @map("Пользователь")
  JUDGE @map("Судья")
  ADMIN @map("Администратор")
  @@map("roles")
}
```

Я сделал запрос к базе и получил следующий результат

```
{
  type: "USER"
}
```

И вот вопрос: можно ли как-то получить значение которое я указал на русском языке (оно в базе именно в таком виде хранится). Понятно, что можно самостоятельно перебирать ответ и выводить нужное, но может есть более правильный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Да можно
Вот есть запрос, чуть его дополним

```
enum Role {
  USER  @map("Пользователь")
  JUDGE @map("Судья")
  ADMIN @map("Администратор")
  @@map("roles")
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  role: Role!
}

query {
  users {
    id
    role
    roleName: _get(Role, role, 'map')
  }
}
```

Вот или так можно
Вот твой код

```
enum Role {
  USER  @map("Пользователь") @value("USER")
  JUDGE @map("Судья") @value("JUDGE")
  ADMIN @map("Администратор") @value("ADMIN")
  @@map("roles")
}
```

Добавим еще чутка)

```
{
  role {
    type
    ...on Role {
      name: type @values
    }
  }
}
```

Вот и получаем!)(получаем json)

```
{
  "data": {
    "role": {
      "type": "USER",
      "name": "Пользователь"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю это работает для graphql, но я не пойму как это изменить под обычные запросы, т.е. мой запрос выглядит так `async findOne(settingsEventFindUniqueArgs: Prisma.SettingsEventFindUniqueArgs ): Promise<SettingsModel> {return await this.prisma.settingsEvent.findUnique({ ...settingsEventFindUniqueArgs,});}`. И куда тогда мне указать решение из первого варианта? И что за метод _get()?

Comment: Попробовал также указать в схеме атрибут @value("..."), пишет что данный атрибут неизвестен. В документации он тоже ни где не фигурирует